# WPF RibbonApplicationMenuItem Command Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, command

Build a menu using the WPF Ribbon. My application is in the MVVM pattern. To connect the RibbonButton the ViewModel, use the form:

```
Command="{Binding Logoff}"
```

It works correctly.
 Now, using the same command on RibbonApplicationMenuItem:

```
 Command="{Binding Logoff}"
```

does not raise any calls or event. What do I need for the RibbonApplicationMenuItem call a method that is in the ViewModel? When I create methods in the codebehind, it works. But this goes against what I'm developing MVVM architecture.
Would have any suggestions to make the RibbonApplicationMenuItem be connected via binding to ViewModel?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, are you needing to pass a parameter to the command in order to decide whether it should log off or log on?

Comment: Where is the DataContext being set? On the root `RibbonWindow` or something else?

Comment: What I do is just run the command. Click the button and a method to be handled. Without parameters.
 The DataContext is set to:

   <Window.DataContext>
         <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
     </ Window.DataContext>

 The problem occurs only in the objects "RibbonApplicationMenuItem." The objects "RibbonButton" work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several searches, I found the solution to the problem. Ribbon in the package has the file MicrosoftRibbonForWPFSourceAndSamples, which has a great example of how to work with RibbonApplicationMenuItem. I used the method DelegateCommand, which comes as an example in this package.

I used the following syntax in the constructor of View:

```
DelegateCommand  = new rbiEfetuarLogoff.Command(mainWindowViewModel.DoLogoff);
```

I hope it's useful for someone else.

Best Regards